# How to split the pattern with fuse.js

Tags: javascript

```
const list = [{ product: "Nike Trail Running Shoes" }]

const options = {
  includeScore: true,
  ignoreLocation: true,
  keys: ["product"],
};

const fuse = new Fuse(list, options);
return fuse.search(pattern);
```

If `pattern = "Nike"` score will be 0.03

But if `pattern = "Nike shoes"` score will be 0.655

I want "Nike shoes" to get a better score than "Nike", since it contains both **Nike** and **shoes**

Can this be solved, so Nike Shoes get a better score? Be aware that the closer 0, the better.

Comment: I ran your code as is and it returns both products when pattern is "Nike shoes". You need to add more info because something else is probably wrong

Comment: My point is "Nike shoes" should have better score than "Nike" cause it contains 2 matching words

Comment: You said "But if pattern = "Nike shoes" it suddenly doesn't return the first product" and I am telling you it does return with your code, also with a higher score than 0.1

Comment: Do you have an idea how to solve this? Somehow ignore where the pattern in keyword shows up

Comment: I edited my question. Hope it makes more sense

Comment: You're saying in your edit that "Nike" gets a 0.03 score and "Nike shoes" gets a 0.655 score, but you want "NIke shoes" to have a better score. IMO the 0.655 score is "better", its a higher number so not sure what you are having issues with

Comment: in fuse.js the lower score (closer to 0) the better

Comment: ah I see, so that's the real question. I took a look through https://fusejs.io/concepts/scoring-theory.html and the only thing I can think of on why it scores lower is because when you search "Nike Shoes" for "Nike Trail Running Shoes" the "Shoes" part in your search is the second word, but the original value has "Trail" there instead. I'm not a fuzzy search expert though.